# How to Query with contacts via Google Contact API filter

Tags: gdata, google-api-client, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts, google-people-api

I was wondering how is there a way to query the user's contacts based on a first name or last name.  I've been looking at the google contacts api and messing with the

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?

I know that you can search looking for key words with the q parameter:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default?v=3&alt=json&q=Test

This call will use the version 3 contact api, return json, and do a search text on "Test".

However, what isn't clear to me is 
1) What is the search text on?  Is it on all the fields relating to a contact?
2) Can you apply the search to a specific field ? 
3) Can it support wild card searches (Ex. a*)

Also what is the difference between the Google Contact API and the Google People API.  It states that you should use the Google People API, but the api doesn't allow you to do searches.  It just returns you all the connections and then info for each connection you specify.

The underlying implementation also seems different. It seems that google contact api is written as a google data api and the other is written as a google api that is discoverable https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1.

Goal:
I want to be able to search a user's contact's and filter the user name by keywords or in this case a wild card.  I want it to return the email, full name.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Try checking the [Retrieving contact groups using query parameters](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contact_groups_using_query_parameters) to know more about querying parameters. As for me, I've only tried the [Retrieving a single contact](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact) by passing the id in the GET request URI. Check my answer on this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695695/people-api-of-google-versus-contacts-api) with regard to difference in People API and Contact API.

Comment: Thanks, I've already looked at those articles.  It seems like the query parameter searches all the text and not specific to a field.

Comment: This question is obsolete / should be updated as the Google Contacts API is deprecated and retired.